# Mule HTTPS endpoint Cluster issue

Tags: https, mule

We are facing one issue when we deploy our Mule application as war on Tomcat cluster on the same server. It works fine when deployed on only one instance.

We have one https connector defined in mule.config file as below,

```
<https:connector name="someConnector" ...doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
<reconnect frequency="5000" count="3"/>
<https:tls-key-store path="${keystr}" keyPassword="${pwd}" storePassword="${pwd}"/>
</https:connector>
```

Above connector is used to make a **Http outbound connection** to a url and in the endpoint we define port as 443, something like below,

```
<https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" password="xxx" user="xxx"    host="${abc}" path="${abc}" port="443" method="GET" connector-ref="someConnector" />
```

Issue occurs when we deploy on Tomcat cluster, since the port is already used from one Tomcat instance, the application gives error on other instance. Below is the error,
Root Exception stack trace:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
            at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
```

Can you please suggest a way to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, that exception is associated with an inbound endpoint. How are your inbound endpoints configured?

Comment: It is failing for this Https outbound endpoint, had checked the logs. Exception looks logical since the port 443 has already been registered on tomcat1 on the server, so it gives exception on tomcat2 on the same server but I am not sure about how to get around this issue ?